# How to get Session of word press from other site If some user is currently active in word-press

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, session

I want to check the status of user session on Site A (WordPress) if it is currently active Then Session Will remain active on Site B. if Site A (wordpress) Session is expire so logout from site B and redirect to Wordpress to login again and site B is not in wordpress it's codeigniter

Comment: Hi Siddique Akbar, welcome to StackOverflow. You are probably interested in the concept of cross-domain cookies. Could you describe in more detail what the exact situation is.

Comment: Just want get session of the word-press site if it is active keep login to other codeigniter site and if session of wordpress expire then logout from codeigniter site and redirect to wordpress to relogin